# React with TypeScript: State Initiations in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, spfx

I have a Long form in TypeScript React App, Where we need to hide/show or enable/disable based on value of status.

```
export interface IState {
  Status: string;
  DisableBasicForm: boolean;
  DisableFeedbackCtrl: boolean;
  DisableTypeofReqCtrl: boolean;
  DisablePurposeCtrl: boolean;
  DisableDutyStation: boolean;
  DisableContractManager: boolean;
  DisableSection: boolean;
  DisableStartDate: boolean;
  DisableEndDate: boolean;
  DisableEstimateDate: boolean;
  DisableTotalBudget: boolean;
  DisableDeliveryDate: boolean;
  DisableWBS: boolean;
  DisableGrant: boolean;
  DisableGrantExpiry: boolean;
  DisableCaseSubmitter: boolean;
  DisablePreparedBy: boolean;
  DisablePreparedDate: boolean;
  ShowSupplyManagerPanel: boolean;
  ShowBudgetOwnerPanel: boolean;
  DisableSupplyManagerPanel: boolean;
  DisableBudgetOwnerPanel: boolean;
}
```

while in class I need to initiate the State in constructor, what would be best way to do, I don't need to initiate very variable present in IState?

```
public constructor(props: IGoodsProps) {
    super(props);
//What should be written here, minimal code required.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with some of the properties having a default value of `undefined`, you can mark them as optional in `IState` using `?`. For example (I'm picking some properties randomly since I don't know your requirements):

```
export interface IState {
  Status: string; // this one is required
  DisableBasicForm?: boolean; // this one is optional
  DisableFeedbackCtrl?: boolean;
  // ...
}
```

Then you can omit the optional properties when initializing the state in the constructor.

**Which properties to make optional?** If you want any of your booleans to be false by default, in many cases `undefined` will work instead because [`undefined` is "falsey"](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-javascript.html) in JavaScript. (can go into more detail if this doesn't make sense)

Answer (score 1):

If you state implement IState, you would need to initiate each property of IState (based on your logic) because properties in IState are not marked as optional.

Pseudo code example:

```
public constructor(props: IGoodsProps) {
    const {status} = this.props
     super(props);
     this.state ={
       Status: status,
       DisableBasicForm: status.Status === 'yourValue',
       ... // initialize here
    } 
}
```

If you have some default value for your state passed as prop you could use object decostructor:

```
public constructor(props: IGoodsProps) {
    const {status} = this.props
     super(props);
     this.state ={
       ...status,
       DisableBasicForm: status.Status === 'yourValue', // just overwrite this property with your logic
    } 
}
```

You can also initialize your state outside the costructor:

```
class Component extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state: State = {
    Status: 'value',
    ... // initialize here
  }

  constructor(props: Props) {
   ...
  }
```

If you have some shared logic for setting your state, and do not want repeat yourself you could evaluate using `React.useState` but you component need to be a function.

Comment: That the thing I don't want, I don't want to add all the state variable, something minimal I need, is it possible?. Currently I am working that way.

Comment: could you post your props here?

Comment: @Durgesh just added an idea using object decostructor.

Comment: Its not coming from props, Its just I don't want to initialize all the values in constructor because that lots of variable

Comment: You can also initialize your state outside the constructor, but you still need to initialize your variable.